# How do I assign Google Apps Script variable with javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How do I assign Google Apps Script variable with javascript variable?

```
<script>
var myJSVariable = <?= myAppScriptVariable ?>;  //works
<? myAppScriptVariable = ?> myJSVariable <? ; ?>  // does not work
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. Do you want to pass a variable from client side to server side? Please be more specific and provide all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML template is not supposed to pass any value to Apps Script Variable. As the doc [states](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates):

> Remember, however, that because template code executes before the page is served to the user, these techniques can only feed initial content to a page. To access Apps Script data from a page interactively, use the `google.script.run` API instead.